# How to get the locale variables of any process?

Tags: linux, locale

When I run the `locale` command in the terminal, the locale variables of the shell will be printed.

Is there a way to get the locale variables of any other process (other than the shell)?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `xargs` on Linux:

```
xargs -r0a "/proc/$pid/environ" sh -c 'exec env -i -- "$@" locale' sh
```

Would run `locale` in a copy of the environment the process of pid `$pid` passed to the command it last executed.

Note that `locale` being external, it only cares about environment variables, not shell variables if they haven't been exported.

The shell itself may have its localisation settings affected even if the `LC_*`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` variables are not exported.

A few notes of caution:

- Programs using localisation usually do a `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` to initialise *all* their localisation settings based on the environment but they don't have to.
- They may call `setlocale()` with different parameters (unlikely).
- They may call it before of after modifying their environment (with APIs like `putenv()`/`setenv()`).
- Those `putenv()`/`setenv()` traditionally don't modify the area exposed by `/proc/$pid/environ` but IIRC it's changing in recent versions of Linux and the GNU libc.
- Regardless of those `putenv()`/`setenv()`, the process may end up modifying their area of the stack exposed by `/proc/$pid/environ` (unlikely).

Another option would be to attach gdb to the process and do:

```
call system("locale")
```

That's quite intrusive though.

That one would use the environment prepared by the process itself (assuming it uses `environ` and/or `putenv()`/`setenv()` which not all applications, especially shells for instance do).

With gdb, you could also actually query the localisation settings directly by calling `setlocale()` for every locale category with a NULL second argument.

To know the value for a  given category:

```
$ printf '#include <locale.h>\nLC_COLLATE\n' | gcc -E -x c - | tail -n 1
3
```

To print the locale name in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p (char*)setlocale(3, 0)
$3 = 0xde8f40 "en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Or:

```
(gdb) x/s setlocale(3, 0)
0xde8f40:       "en_GB.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in the shell, calling `locale` will not always give you reliable results.

The Bourne Shell e.g. imports environment variables into the local shell variables and forwards the imported values to it's children, but at the same time permits to modify the related local variables without modifying the exported value. The Bourne Shell locale setup is based on the internal values of the shell variables and not on the imported or exported environment.

Since this applies to the LC_* variables, the Bourne Shell could run in a different locale than the `locale` command reports. BTW: you may change this by calling `set -o posix` in the Bourne Shell...to tell the Bourne Shell to sync exported values from imported variables with the internal value.

Even more: Since POSIX.1-2008, there is a way to let a program use multiple locales at the same time. This is e.g. important for compilers that like to parse e.g. floating point constants in the US based `C` locale where the unusual floating fraction separator '.' is used, while still giving warnings and other output based on a different locale.

The same method is also frequently used to let threaded programs use different locales for different threads.

As you see, looking at the environment of other programs can only give a coarse overview of what the locale may be, but never returns true granted results.